# String comma separated matrix into double separated matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a stream of data coming from my com port and I want to separate it's data in the following format:

t v1 v2 v3 v4 \n t v1 v2 v3 v4

the data comes in the buffer line by line in the following format:
t,v1,v2,v3,v4 \n t,v1,v2,v3,v4 \n t,v1,v2,v3,v4....

I already created some vectors to accumulate the comming data as they come. I read the port all at once after a small pause (simulating the processing time in the original big code).

Here is the minimized portion of the reading and conversion of the com port content:

```
            clear all;
    clc;

    v1=zeros(10000,1);v2=zeros(10000,1);v3=zeros(10000,1);v4=zeros(10000,1);
    time=zeros(10000,1);

    comport= serial('COM11', 'BaudRate', 115200);
    comport.InputBufferSize = 50000000;
    flushinput(comport);
    fopen(comport);pause(10);
    tic;dat=[];in=1;
    while(toc<50)
        %             dat=strsplit(fgetl(comport),',');
        while length(dat)~=5
            dat=(strsplit(fgetl(comport),','));
        end

        u8 = fread(comport, comport.BytesAvailable); % uchar, but in double
        ch = char(u8);

        x=string(ch');
        newStr = splitlines(x);
        %             newStr=newStr(1:length(newStr)-1);
        data=zeros(length(newStr),5);
        %         data=[];
        i=1;n=1;r=[];
        while(i<=length(newStr))
            r=str2double(strsplit(newStr(i),','));
            if(length(r)==5)
                data(n,:)= r;
                n=n+1;
            end
            i=i+1;
        end
        data = data(~any(isnan(data), 2), :);
        data=double(data);
        j=1;
        while(j<=length(data))
            time(in)=data(j,1);
            v1(in) = (data(j,2));
            v2(in) =  (data(j,3));
            v3(in)=  (data(j,4));
            v4(in) =  (data(j,5));
            in=in+1;
            j=j+1;
        end
    end
    fclose(comport);
    delete(comport);
```

whenever I try to run this code it works sometimes but in other times, I get the following error:

```
   Error in freadtry (line 28)
        data(i,:)= str2double(strsplit(newStr(i),','));
        Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

can you tell me why this error keeps happening?

EDIT: I've located the error and fixed it, it was related to the size of some "newStr" rows which had less than 5 elements.

Comment: Can you check the value of `newStr` and `i` when the error occur?

Comment: i=4050 and newStr(i)

ans = 

    "561.578,2.02,2.02,2.0"

Comment: I think I located the problem location, each line of newStr must have 5 elements separated by a ',' however, the last raw didn't have that, how can I remove lines that do not have 4 commas?

Comment: You can just check the result of `strsplit` before assigning it to `data(i, :)`

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to your question, it is a good idea to add answer instead and to clean up your original post. This will make your post much more interesting for other people with the same question/problem as you, see [ask]

Answer (score -1):

I've located the error and fixed it, it was related to the size of some "newStr" rows which had less than 5 elements.
To solve it, my loop now takes every line and saves it in (r), then evaluate the length of it, if it was less than 5 it will discard this line as an incomplete. Else, it will add it to the final vector.

Comment: yes I understand that the last part of the answer is a question, I copied it by mistake from the Edit part in my question. I revised my answer and re-posted it.